# Messages not exchanged between content scripts, background.js and popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google-chrome extension which fetches selected text from the webpage and displays it in the popup. I've read google-chrome docs and have followed many questions but I have been unable to resolve this issue. Selected text cannot be sent to background.js and furthur to popup.js.

**manifest.json:**

```
    {
    "name": "Wordomania",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Displays word on popup",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/W.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "jquery-3.3.1.js",
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "background",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/W.png",
        "default_title": "Wordomania"

    }
}
```

**background.js :**

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log('Extension button clicked');
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {
        action: 'sendWord'
    }, function (wordObject) {
        console.log('Word received');
        let obj = {
            word: wordObject.word,
            from: 'back'
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(obj, function (status) {
            console.log(status);
        });
    });
});
```

**content.js :**

```
    function getSelectionText() {
    let text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== 'Control') {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === 'sendWord') {
        let text = getSelectionText();
        sendResponse({word: text});
    }
});
```

**popup.html :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wordomania</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><p id="word"></p></h1>
<div id="body-of-popup"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Help required!**

Comment: If you already defined the `default_popup`, you can't have a listener for `browserAction.onClicked`.

Comment: I removed it. It started to log on the console. But still it couldn't retrieve selected text from **content.js**. When I tried to `console.log(JSON.stringify(wordObject))` it said `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will need to do a few changes in your approach. Since, we can have only one event at a time assoiciated with the browserAction either popup or `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`. In your case you have a popup assoiciated so you can not use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`.

But still you can achieve what you want using the code below.

> // Add below code in your popup.js

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "sendWord"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.word);
        });
    });
};
```

Let the your `content.js` file as is.

> manifest.json

```
 "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/W.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Wordomania"

    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I get your concept and I did the same. But now the popup doesn't show when the extension button is clicked.

Comment: Its not showing because you havn't mentioned it in the manifest.json file. See my updated answer.